# How to make advanced future humans extinct/get rid of them?

Tags: extinction, cataclysms

Before you VTC, some things to address:

- Yes I know, this question has been asked before, but my question has some specific requirements, and I haven't seen a good answer to fits the requirements in the other questions.
- This is not "writing the story for me" since the whole extinct humans thing is just a backdrop.

With that out of the way,

It is somewhere between the 25th and 31st century(2400-3000), and Humans have advanced in their technology, but for the purposes of my story, I need to get rid of them. **How can I rid the planet of these future Humans?** They don't have to go extinct, but if they do just leave the planet or something, they shouldn't be able to return to Earth for at least 10 million years or so. The disaster doesn't have to be natural, it can be man-made, but the disaster cannot be caused by some malfunction or big oversight(example: Nanorobots were deployed in the blood-stream of everybody, making them immortal, however a malfunction in them caused them to help cancer cells instead of regular cells).

**Requirements:**

- The planet cannot be destroyed
- The Human's structures and buildings must remain intact(mostly, not *ALL* of them need to remain intact, but just a majority)
- The surface can't be completely sterilized, there is still some hardy and resistant life scampering around(say, rats, or racoons or something)
- If you decide to not go the extinction route, then whatever method of ridding the planet of humans you choose must make it so that the humans and/or their descendants cannot return for many millions of years.
- Not ALL of the humans have to go extinct, in this future, the humans have done the thing where the planet is exhausted, climate is screwed, and global warming and pollution are big; so if you kill most of the humans, or make it so that their technology is kaput, then the rest of the humans
  will die off from the not-so-good conditions.

**The Technology that will be standing in your way**

- Their technology is immune against EMPs(most military technology already has this kind of technology, and since solar flares can cause EMPs, and wars might use EMPs, it seems plausible that these future humans have EMP-shielding technology implemented widespread.)
- They have agricultural technology that allows them to make lots of food indoors using machinery, and without the need for large fields and such, so it will be hard to get them to die from starvation alone
- In general their technology makes them pretty self-sufficient for the survival necessities(food, water, electricity), e.g. Killing off everybody in the hemisphere will disrupt the manufacture of a ton of goods, but life on the other hemisphere will recover and go on fairly quickly and easily, save for the economy taking a big hit
- They have the technology so that they are not dying/taking a big hit from the bad conditions they caused from global warming/pollution/stuff, after all, it wouldn't get as bad as it is if they were dying from it too.
- They have very advanced medical technology, so any virus and like can be treated well before it causes an extinction

Comment: How long do their buildings need to remain intact? Surely not for "10 million years or so".

Comment: Given that there are many ways humans could die off asking us to tell you how is effectively writing your story or building your world for you. The fact that it’s in the past doesn’t change this fact. Any questions with many valid answers isn’t suitable for this site.

Comment: @Cadence Their buildings are made from handwavium, so that it will take them a very long time to break down(Although things like tall buildings will collapse relatively quickly simply from the stress of holding their own weight for so long.) In the story, 10 million years in the future, a species of prokaryote evolve that break down the Handwavium into fluorine-containing gases(which are like 10,000x global warming potential of CO2) and heat up the planet into a venus-like hellscape conditions.

Comment: Asimov just made future humans forget where earth was and go on living on other planets, that doesn't sound that bad.

Comment: If it's just a backdrop, I've already come up with fifteen possible routes for this for my own fiction. That makes this a brainstorming question, which isn't particularly appropriate. We seriously underestimate how fragile mankind is.

Comment: After all that detail, can you explain how 'They don't have to go extinct, but… they shouldn't be able to return… for… 10 million years or so' works? Could make anything specific?

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but you might enjoy reading [Margaret Atwood's Oryx and Crake](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/46756.Oryx_and_Crake) (and the other two books in the trilogy).

Answer (score 24):

/ the whole extinct humans thing is just a backdrop/

**Then you don't need to be specific.**

And this unresolved issue can be grist for your prose mill.  Whatever protagonists carry your story through this abandoned future, they can speculate from time to time on the fate of the humans who used to be there.  Was it the Rapture, and everyone got taken?  Are they hiding in cryosleep somewhere underground?  Maybe Earth from an alternate timeline bumped into this earth and all the people from both wound up on one?  Maybe the people turned into bugs?

The character with the bug theory can be roundly mocked.  Over the course of the story some weird things go down with bugs and each time this character nods knowingly.  The character can be noted to be talking with bugs but dismisses it - "just having a chat".

---

I picture the very end of the story where your main character is lying on the grass and a butterfly lands on her knee.  Then 2 more.  "Hey," she says.

Comment: I think it is almost a pity you do not write the story yourself. I am literally sorry the answer is so short. +1

Answer (score 7):

### Digital Ascension leading to civilisation-collapse

Otherwise known to some as the Rapture of the Nerds.

Humanity has worked out how to upload their minds into computers and developed a new digital way of life from there.
Maybe it's a kind of heaven.
Maybe they're now a gestalt intelligence.

Whatever the case may be, a critical-mass of people opted to upload themselves and effectively removed themselves from civilisation.
This process probably started with the technology-centric parts of society and spread outwards from there.

This gutted the technological heart of civilisation, leaving only those who opted not to participate. Possibly for religious, or spiritual or just plain fear reasons.
After all, what ends up in the computer may not be *me* anymore. Just a copy of my mind-state created by killing me..
Or perhaps my religious leaders say I can't reach heaven if I choose this path.
Maybe I can't afford the upgrade, or I'm just not willing to give up being a good old fashioned Human 1.0.

The ones left behind after all is said and done are not equipped or populous enough to maintain the technological infrastructure of a billions-strong civilisation, and so those systems collapse.
They lack the knowledge or tools to maintain and develop the advanced computer hardware they use on a routine basis, and so that collapses too.
Their just-in-time manufacture and food industries collapse.

In time, all that is left are isolated communities that have regressed to old ways, maybe slowly reinventing a life lived with minimal technology, but more likely dwindling in number as pollution and climate-damage take their toll.

The great cities and constructions of humanity crumble around them year after year, and in deep archival bunkers and lunar server-farms, the ascended humanity enjoy their eternity in whatever way they see fit.

Comment: Like a story set after Neal Stephenson's 'Fall'. I find the idea that humanity (almost) collectively chooses its fate to be pretty compelling.

Answer (score 5):

### Behavioral sink

I think Willk's advice is good, but I also think that even if a work (wisely) chooses to never reveal the actual facts for why everybody is gone, the author might still need to secretly have some of those details nailed down **to ensure that the facts which are presented are all consistent**.

So, here's my proposal: human society ended up imploding because it collectively lost the ability to think critically and act appropriately. Basically, everybody ate Tide pods and died, or took the bleach challenge and died, or did some kind of Brexit-but-for-global-agriculture and mostly starved, or did a pogrom against people who worked in water treatment, etc.

Collectively, society's thinking became disconnected enough from reality that humans let foolish impulses or trends or inconvenient fashion make important decisions badly, with catastrophic consequences.

Comment: My first thought was similar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_sink, but this does not prevent recolonization for another million years.

Comment: Basically Wall-E, except the planet isn't ruined and there was no cute little robot to save us

Comment: That would be a slow *Idiocracy* decline.

Comment: +1 and it'd be another +1 just for "some kind of Brexit-but-for-global-agriculture" if I could!

Answer (score 3):

### Neutron Bombs/Beams

Neutron weapons are what comes to mind first if you see seemingly intact infrastructure but no life. The buildings will take some damage in the form of neuron activation and embrittlement, so it should be pretty clear what happend. Why it happend or who did it is yours to explain.

### Spontaneous Disappearance

Under the many worlds interpretation of quantum physics there exists an infinite set of universes where all inhabitants of Earth just spontaneously disappeared. Admittedly, it is a smaller infinite set, but still a possible option. Your characters just happened to be in such a universe. Thus also neatly explains why some survivors would exist.

### Cognito or Infohazard

Some piece of information spread across the civilization that lead to its extinction. Maybe a signal that made everyone commit suicide was broadcasted. Or some entity or group spread strong anti-natalist ideas throughout the cultures over decades.

### Essentially Magic

Something with technology that could locally alter physics in a way that made life impossible attacked and disappeared again. They encountered an outside context problem and were annihilated. Kinda like cultists actually summoning an elder god or middle schoolers finding out that Bloody Mary isn't a myth.

### Devolution Virus

A harmless seeming virus that lets intelligence collapse back to animal levels over a few generations.

### Killer Robots

Swarms of small war robots got out of control. They took over their factories and purged the planet. Why did the system do this? Why did it not proceed to turn the universe into paperclips? Noone knows. Mind you, those bots might have rather obscure objectives, so there is a lot of story potential here.

Answer (score 2):

## Demographic Collapse.

---

You future humanity was under a world government. Everything was going great, but the earth's population continued to climb at an alarmingly fast rate. Concerned that there wouldn't be enough to go around. The future world government (FWG) enacted a one child policy to reduce human population to something more sustainable.

The implementation of this one child policy was just as effective as China's. It caused a massive demographic upheaval. 20 years after the massive demographic switch, the massive imbalance between male/female's was noted... (This is assuming that the FWG hasn't greatly changed the culture of India, China, large swathes of africa...).

This led to the one child policy being replaced with a two child policy. The FWG supported this changed because they had realized that there wouldn't be enough laborers to support the inverted triangles social welfare programs.

But the culture change that the one child policy had caused proved to be to large a boulder to undo... There one child propaganda proved to convincing to change and the average total children per women remained below 1 child per women. And with a heavily unbalanced population this led to the next and final generation of humanity to be vastly smaller...

40 years after the sheer number of unmarried men leads massive riots/violent outbursts. To be known for a short number of years as "the bride wars." This was not a war of nation states. No weapons of mass destruction, or even armies... It is just days of madness driven by unmet needs and despair. The few pockets of humanity that survived the bloodbaths fade away in a world no longer fit for humanities habitation. Because they are unable to maintain the machines that kept the planet running.

Answer (score 1):

## They never solved immortality

While genetic technology advanced a lot, they never managed to extend life much beyond 150 years. Genetic and biological complexities meant that everyone would eventually die.

## A remote star has an alien lifeform that grants immortality

Some ancient alien civilization designed some advanced organism that can grant immortality. Due to arcane details of the much more advanced alien civilization they can't transplant this to earth.

## Humanity decided to move to this other planet en masse

Because everyone deserves immortality, humanity decided to migrate en masse. Robots and nanites were set to preserve humanity's home for the future, and everyone was put on a colony ship or forced to go, per the political consensus.

Earth now has no humans, just dispassionate AIs and robots maintaining the world for a humanity that has no intention of ever returning. Humanity is doing great on the alien planet exploring the advanced technological constructs of the alien civilization, and the biosphere is much more friendly to humans than earth's.

Answer (score 0):

## They Intermingled

The human race spread out into the Galaxy and... intermingled. Many races came to the Earth and did the same.

In the same way we modern humans look quite different to early hominids, the story-era inhabitants look at the alien (to them) skeletal remains and wonder what happened. Human history becomes a footnote in Galactic history.

Historians and archaeologists may know what happened, but it will often not be taught in schools even to those who can trace their ancestry back that far. After all, its more important that kids today know about the creation of the Federation/Glorious Empire than which caveman lobbed nukes at which other caveman.

If you need the Earth to be largely empty (of humans), make the Earth the equivalent of a mining town where the mine went dry -- this would go well with the climate change option. After all, we have been pulling stuff out of the ground for millennia. Any visiting space craft would find easier pickings down shallower gravity wells in moons and asteroids.

Answer (score 0):

### Grey goo

It's not precluded by any of the defenses you said they have: EMP-shielding, automated agriculture, etc.

They seem to be a high-tech culture, so they should have a high-tech problem.

Grey goo, which most of you reading this are probably familiar with, is a hypothetical virulent self-replicating nanobot. This is sometimes imagined as a seething macro-scale mass nomming buildings and everything in sight, but for your purposes (leave everything intact but the people), it  would be a nanobot the size of a bacterium, but metallic/mechanical, 1000× tougher than any virus fits the bill. Essentially a bacterial disease, but robotic.

This could be released by a lone-wolf psychopath if that fits your story.

Answer (score 0):

### Resource Depletion

Technology relies on making things from things, but over time, the things you make your stuff from runs out, and recycling your old things into new things gets harder and harder.

The Earth is running out of economically viable fossil fuels, rare Earth metals, mineral fertilizers, etc. As we go, we can replace fossil fuels with better power sources like fusion, bring in rare Earth metals from space and/or get much better about recycling our electronics, and stop pumping all our valuable feces into the Ocean so that we can reclaim that much needed potassium and phosphate... but new, easy, virgin resources that just sit around on Earth's surface waiting to be exploited are always getting harder to come by, and stuff that can be recycled is always being tainted by things that make it harder to recycle.

An overly simplified example is this: A cereal box is much easier to recycle than a pizza box because all the mixed in food would ruin your new paper.  If you could recycle paper over and over again, it would eventually all end up as useless tainted pizza boxes.  This same principle applies to all of our resources as eventually everything will become tainted by something that makes it really hard to refine.

By 3000CE, the issue is not that people (and life) can not exist on Earth, it's just a lot more work, and a lot more expensive to make things on a depleted world.  A thing that takes 1mwh of power and a few simple machines to produce now will take 100kwh and a complex scavenging and recycling infrastructure in the future.

Eventually the increasing cost of dwindling resources will make many industries fail.  We'll have to just stop making things we can't afford to make any more.  This will cause technology to slowly backslide as our need for more technology increases, our ability to make it wains.  Eventually this leads to famines, wars, genocides, etc.

In the end, the Earth is still able to more-or-less support life... there are just no good resources left to attract the investment of any future civilizations wanting to establish an advanced technology infrastructure here.

Answer (score 0):

## Earth went right

As Humans began to explore space they left behind a utopia, robots farmed and mined and while pollutants and toxins built in the atmosphere, air filtration and dome living easily kept pace. Human life was good, robots worked to serve them in most aspects of life, but humanity continued much like star trek... improving yourself and building reputation became currency as needs were increasingly free to acquire. As pollutants built up, the number of sustainable domes diminished but not by any threatening numbers.

### Chirality

For whatever reason, pollution, reduced sunlight, cosmic rays, or god just got mad. Chemistry on earth began to favor right-handed amino acids and left handed sugars, opposite of what life as we know it requires. Most chemical reactions split evenly between right and left handed versions. Life however, seems to have a preference. Once chemistry stopped working correctly on Earth food could not be relied on to be nutritious. As the Humans on Earth scrambled to reprogram their robots to detect and destroy right handed crops, right handed micro-organisms, right handed viruses, etc. Their ability to produce a sustainable amount of food vanished. Famine, Right Handed Plague, and Toxins drove the last humans away from the surface of Earth in such a rush the automated factories and farms weren't even shut down. So now, armies of farming robots pile tons of inedible food that simply decays into silos and factories produce all manner of goods that go unsold on store shelves, the planet is entirely automated, but no one knows what is edible, what you can touch without it leeching poison into your skin, what new microbes your body has no resistance to float in the air.

Answer (score 0):

Asteroid Impact: A large enough asteroid impact could potentially cause widespread destruction and disrupt the advanced human society, making survival difficult or impossible.

Supervolcanic Eruption: If a supervolcano erupts, it could cause a volcanic winter, potentially leading to the extinction of the advanced human society.

Extraterrestrial Invasion: An extraterrestrial invasion could pose a threat to advanced human society if the aliens have technologically advanced weapons or methods of destroying or enslaving the human population.

Climate Change: Despite advanced technology to mitigate the effects of global warming and pollution, a rapid and catastrophic shift in climate could still occur and lead to the extinction of the advanced human society.

Solar Flare: A massive solar flare could cause widespread damage to technological infrastructure and disrupt the advanced human society, leading to their decline.

Internal Conflict: Despite advanced technology, internal conflicts such as civil war, coups, or revolutions could still occur and lead to the decline or extinction of the advanced human society.

Answer (score -1):

## Tik Tok,

AI virtual partners, and other technological diversions distracted them from the hard work of maintaining relationships and raising children.

Once the birth rate fell below the replacement rate, then end of the human race was inevitable.

Comment: Seem implausible. I would imagine, that in such case natural selection would kick in. Namely, people with certain mutations would be more willing to have children than an Average Joe (or too dumb to use contraceptives properly). And consequently, said people would overtake the population. Think about "Idiocracy". I have better idea. What if they are all forced to overwork and thus have zero time and energy for relationships and parenting? Like real life Japanese.

Comment: I think this idea works if the story is engaging with it directly, like John Ringo's 'There Will Be Dragons', rather than as a backdrop. While technological diversions are and will affect many aspects of daily life, there will always be those who prefer the analog and the manual, as well as those who seek to prevent such an end at any cost.

Comment: Seams about right for how things are going for my generation, which is Gen z. also kinda funny